# ifelse test selecting a single value instead of two

Tags: r, if-statement

First, I created the object sym to lable my plot with M and F instead of Male and Female respectively.

```
sym <- ifelse(students$gender=="male", "M", "F")
```

Then, I used sym as pch to get the plot with M and F symbols appearing in the graph itself.

```
plot(students$height, students$shoesize, pch=sym)
```

The problem is I am getting the graphs with all "F" symbol and not both "M" and "F".

Can anyone identify the problem with the code and suggest the solution?

Comment: What programming language you are using? Tag that with your question

Comment: I used R language Jayendran. Thanks

Comment: because there is no `"male"` in students$gender. try doing `table(students$gender)` and see what happens

Comment: Is it `"Male"` or `"male"`? R is case sensitive.